# Animation OnTrigger Unity

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, camera

I'm trying to make a fly-pan camera of a room when my first person player goes inside it. I've already recorded the animation on the camera but I'm having trouble when I change between cameras. I have read a lot a research about it but I actually don't know what I'm doing wrong. I would appreciate any kind of help. Thanks!

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    inTrigger = true;
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    inTrigger = false;
}
void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
    cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (inTrigger/*&& !anim.isPlaying*/)
    {
        anim.Play("AnimateCameraFirst");
    }

    if (anim.IsPlaying("AnimateCameraFirst"))
    {
        cam.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        FPCam.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    else
    {
        FPCam.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;
        cam.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Update()` is not necessary here. Following code should be enough:

first, change `FPCam` `GameObject` to `Camera` to avoid `GetComponent` calls:

```
public Camera FPCam; // you have to reassign camera reference through inspector.
Camera cam; // as usual

void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
    cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    anim.Play("AnimateCameraFirst");
    cam.enabled = true;
    FPCam.enabled = false;
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    FPCam.enabled = true;
    cam.enabled = false;
}
```

To Run some code when animation finishes you have to create animation event and register your method to it. [Have a look](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html) at how to implement this.

you can create this method and register it to the event which fires right at the end of animation:

```
public void CameraFirstAnimation_Stopped()
{
    FPCam.enabled = true;
    cam.enabled = false;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: He Umair, thanks for the answer.

Your code modify a bit what I'm trying to do, because on it the animation play when the player is OnTriggerEnter and change the camera back when the player is OnTriggerExit, I want my camera back when the animation is finished (which I can calculate with my actual code). Also I still have the same error as before which is a message on the screen saying "Display 1, No cameras rendering".
I hope it help you to understand my problem. 

Thanks so much anyway!

Comment: I have updated the answer. This will help you solve the problem.

Comment: Hey Umair! Thanks so much for your help! I've found the error, basically my animation camera had a different Target Display as the main one, that is way was not rendering. Thanks so much!